# Remarquable identities $f(n) = \frac{a^n}{(a-b)(a-c)} + \frac{b^n}{(b-a)(b-c)} + \frac{c^n}{(c-a)(c-b)}$

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, inverse

Let $n$ be an integer, and

\begin{equation}
f(n) = \frac{a^n}{(a-b)(a-c)} + \frac{b^n}{(b-a)(b-c)} + \frac{c^n}{(c-a)(c-b)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
g(n) = \frac{(bc)^n}{(a-b)(a-c)} + \frac{(ac)^n}{(b-a)(b-c)} + \frac{(ab)^n}{(c-a)(c-b)}
\end{equation}

We have the following impressive identities, for all $a,b,c$,

\begin{align}
f(0) &= 0 \\ 
f(1) &= 0 \\
f(2) &= 1 \\
f(3) &= a+b+c \\
f(4) &= a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + ab + ac + bc \\
f(5) &= a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + a^2b + a^2c + b^2c + ab^2 + ac^2 + bc^2 \\
f(6) &= a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + a^3b + a^3c + b^3c + ab^3 + ac^3 + bc^3 + a^2bc + ab^2c + abc^2 +a^2b^2 + a^2c^2 + b^2c^2 \\
 \\
g(0) &= 0 \\ 
g(1) &= 1 \\
g(2) &= ab + ac + bc \\
g(3) &= a^2b^2 + a^2c^2 + b^2c^2 + a^2bc + ab^2c + abc^2 \\
g(4) &= a^3b^3 + a^3c^3 + b^3c^3 + a^3b^2c + a^3bc^2 + a^2b^3c + ab^3c^2 + a^2bc^3 + ab^2c^3 + a^2b^2c^2     
\end{align}

which I have verified by plugging the expressions into Wolfram Alpha. It seems that the general form should be, for $n > 2$.

\begin{align}
f(n) &= \sum_{i+j+k = n-2}a^ib^jc^k \\
g(n) &= \sum_{\substack{i+j+k = 2(n-1)\\1\leq i,j,k \leq n-1}}a^ib^jc^k
\end{align}

The questions are :

1. How to demonstrate the statements for $n$ general using induction. Intuitively, we should use induction, however I do not see the induction step.
2. Could we demonstrate the general case without using induction ? There is a link, between these formulas and Vandermondt matrices (see below), would there be a nice demonstration using matrices ?

=======================================================================

I arrived at such identities when working with partial fractions decomposition,
and after some related work I realized that the Vandermondt matrices where almost the inverse of the matrices which appear when we do partial fractions decomposition,
Then I realised that the Vandermondt matrices have very nice inverse :

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1 \\
a&b 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{b}{(a - b)} & \frac{1}{(a - b)} \\
-\frac{a}{(b - a)} & \frac{1}{(b - a)} \\
\end{pmatrix}
= I_{2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1 \\
a&b&c \\
a^2&b^2&c^2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{b c}{(a - b) (a - c)} & -\frac{b + c}{(a - b) (a - c)} & \frac{1}{(a - b) (a - c)} \\
\frac{a c}{(b - a) (b - c)} & -\frac{a + c}{(b - a) (b - c)} & \frac{1}{(b - a) (b - c)} \\
\frac{a b}{(c - a) (c - b)} & -\frac{a + b}{(c - a) (c - b)} & \frac{1}{(c - a) (c - b)}
\end{pmatrix}
= I_{3}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1 \\
a&b&c&d \\
a^2&b^2&c^2&d^2 \\
a^3&b^3&c^3&d^3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{bcd}{(a - b) (a - c)(a-d)} & \frac{bc + cd + bd}{(a - b) (a - c)(a-d)} &-\frac{b+c+d}{(a - b) (a - c)(a-d)} &  \frac{1}{(a - b) (a - c)(a-d)}\\
-\frac{a cd}{(b - a) (b - c)(b-d)} & \frac{ac + ad + cd}{(b - a) (b - c)(b-d)} & -\frac{a + c + d}{(b - a) (b - c)(b-d)}& \frac{1}{(b - a) (b - c)(b-d)}\\
-\frac{a bd}{(c - a) (c - b)(c-d)} & \frac{ab + ad + bd}{(c - a) (c - b)(c-d)} & -\frac{a + b + d}{(c - a) (c - b)(c-d)}&\frac{1}{(c - a) (c - b)(c-d)}\\
-\frac{a bc}{(d - a) (d - b)(d-c)} & \frac{ab + ac + bc}{(d - a) (d - b)(d-c)} & -\frac{a + b + c}{(d - a) (d - b)(d-c)}&\frac{1}{(d - a) (d - b)(d-c)}
\end{pmatrix}
= I_{4}
\end{equation}

The identities $f(0),f(1), f(2)$ are the last column of the inverse equation for 3-dim matrices. However, it seems that such matrix argument is not sufficient to prove the case for $n$ general, and that many similar identities (the other places in the matrices) should exist.

Comment: Quick note: Incorporating $a$, $b$, $c$ into the function parameters, we can write
$$g(n,a,b,c) = ( a b c )^{n-1}\cdot f\left(n+1,\frac1a,\frac1b,\frac1c\right)$$
Eg, using your reductions, 
$$g(2,a,b,c) = a b+b c+c a = a b c \left(\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\right)=a b c\;f\left(1,\frac1a,\frac1b,\frac1c\right)$$
So, a formula for $g$ will follow from a formula for $f$; you don't have to consider it separately.

Comment: By the way: Your $f(2)$, $f(3)$, $f(4)$, $f(5)$ match the [complete homogeneous symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_homogeneous_symmetric_polynomial#Examples) for $n=3$.

Comment: Interestingly enough and easily shown, $$f(n;ax,bx,cx)=x^{n-2}f(n;a,b,c)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With respect to your first question, I don't think induction would be a method that is very helpful here. The problem would be to relate different functions $f(n)$. This is more something that asks for generating functions.

\begin{eqnarray}
f(n) 
& = & \frac{a^n}{(a-b)(a-c)} + \frac{b^n}{(b-a)(b-c)} + \frac{c^n}{(c-a)(c-b)} \\ \\
& = & \frac{(a b^n + b c^n + c a^n) - (a^n b + b^n c + c^n a) }{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)} \\ \\
& = & \frac{(a^n - b^n) c - a b (a^{n-1} - b^{n-1})   - (a - b) c^n}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}
\end{eqnarray}

For $n=0$ and $n=1$ we see from the second line immediately that the numerator will be zero.

So we only need to consider the case $n \geq 2$. The third line tells us that the numerator is a polynomial in $a,b,c$ with all terms of degree $n+1$. In addition to has a factor $(a-b)$, and like-wise due to symmetry it also has a factors $(b-c)$ and $c-a$. It therefore follows that $f(n)$ is a polynomial in $a,b,c$ with all terms of degree $n-2$.

From this point one could in principle assume that the proposed form is correct, multiply with $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$, expand everything, and manipulate the sums until the above form is obtained. It is actually not too difficult. There is, however, an easier approach.

Consider the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \epsilon^n f(n)$ in the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$   ( $|\epsilon| \max(|a|,|b|,|c|) < 1$ for which the sum will converge. We then find
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \epsilon^n f(n) & = & \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\epsilon^n  a^n}{(a-b)(a-c)} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\epsilon^n b^n}{(b-a)(b-c)} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\epsilon^n c^n}{(c-a)(c-b)} \\ \\
& = & 
\frac{1}{(a-b)(a-c)(1-\epsilon a)} + \frac{1}{(b-a)(b-c)(1-\epsilon b)} + \frac{1}{(c-a)(c-b)(1-\epsilon c)} \\ \\
& = & \frac{\epsilon^2}{(1-\epsilon a)(1-\epsilon b)(1-\epsilon c)} \\ \\
& = & \epsilon^2 \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty (\epsilon a)^k \right) \left( \sum_{l=0}^\infty (\epsilon b)^l \right) \left( \sum_{m=0}^\infty (\epsilon c)^m \right) \\ \\
& = & \epsilon^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \epsilon^n \sum_{k+l+m=n} a^k b^l c^m \\ \\
& = & \sum_{n=2}^\infty \epsilon^n \sum_{k+l+m=n-2} a^k b^l c^m
\end{eqnarray}
From which it follows that $f(n)$ is the complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial of degree $n-2$, and that $f(0)=f(1)=0$.

In view of the comment by [Blue](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/409/blue), the results for $g$ follows.

I don't know whether there is formulation by using matrices that is easier.

Comment: This method of introducing epsilon to polynomial series is quite genius! How did you get to know such method?

Comment: As is often the case in mathematics you do a lot of it and try to remember different approaches and techniques. If you look for "generating functions" you will find that this is just an application of that.

Answer (score 1):

Using the method that @RonaldBlaak used, we see that
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ge0}z^ng(n)&=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(bcz)^n}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(acz)^n}{(b-a)(b-c)}+\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(abz)^n}{(c-a)(c-b)}\\
&=\frac{1}{(a-b)(a-c)(1-bcz)}+\frac{1}{(b-a)(b-c)(1-acz)}+\frac{1}{(c-a)(c-b)(1-abz)}\\
&=\frac{z}{(1-bcz)(1-acz)(1-bcz)}\\
&=z\left(\sum_{i\ge0}(bcz)^i\right)\left(\sum_{j\ge0}(acz)^j\right)\left(\sum_{k\ge0}(abz)^k\right)\\
&=z\sum_{n\ge0}z^n\sum_{i+j+k=n}(bc)^i(ac)^j(ab)^k\\
&=\sum_{n\ge0}z^{n+1}\sum_{i+j+k=n}a^{j+k}b^{i+k}c^{i+j}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge0}z^{n+1}\sum_{i+j+k=n}a^{n-i}b^{n-j}c^{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge1}z^n(abc)^{n-1}\sum_{i+j+k=n-1}a^{-i}b^{-j}c^{-k},
\end{align}$$
thus showing that $g(0;a,b,c)=0$ and $$g(n;a,b,c)=\sum_{i+j+k=n-1}a^{n-1-i}b^{n-1-j}c^{n-1-k}=(abc)^{n-1}\sum_{i+j+k=n-1}a^{-i}b^{-j}c^{-k},$$
which lends itself to the relation, as was pointed out in the comments,
$$g(n;a,b,c)=(abc)^{n-1}f\left(n+1;\frac1a,\frac1b,\frac1c\right).$$
Nicely enough, this is still a polynomial :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be mentioned that this is one of the [Schur polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial#Definition_(Jacobi%27s_bialternant_formula)).